# Comfortably legible base font-size?

Tags: accessibility, typography, responsive, legibility, font-sizes

I'm trying to figure out a comfortably legible base font-size for all screen sizes, on a platform that supports several languages. Anyone worked on a similar project? If so, what was your outcome and why? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I highly recommed Richard Rutter's book on Web Typography. http://book.webtypography.net/ Have a look at things like vmin in CSS to be truly responsive.

Answer (score 2):

The Web Content Accessibility Guidelines recommend that any web font sizes be adjustable by the user.

For large fonts WCAG says:
"The actual size of the character that a user sees is dependent both on the author-defined size and the user's display or user-agent settings. For many mainstream body text fonts, 14 and 18 point is roughly equivalent to 1.2 and 1.5 em or to 120% or 150% of the default size for body text (assuming that the body font is 100%), but authors would need to check this for the particular fonts in use." -- https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/

If large fonts are 14 pts, standard body font should be around 12 pts.